# return item with closest time from now JavaScript / Moment.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I am working on an application related to logs and times. I have this array with objects (logs). I would like to find the object with the `checkin_time` (which is a property from the object) closest to now. So If I have two objects, one with an `checkin_time` from "2018-04-05 08:04:12" and one with "2018-04-05 10:02:12" I would like to find the object with "2018-04-05 10:02:12" because that one is the closest time from now.

I tried something with the Moment.js library but that didn't worked out. I am using the Vue framework.

UPDATE

I've tried one of the answers below but I still got undefined back. Is there something I don't see?

Code

```
methods: {
    getLog() {


        this.users.forEach(element => {

            element.logs.forEach((log) => {

                this.Logs.push(log);

            })

        });

        var unfinished = this.Logs.filter((log) => {
            return log.finished == false;
        });

        console.log(unfinished);

        const input = [
            {id: 1, checkin_time: "2030-05-05 10:22:02"}, // 10 AM. 
            {id: 2, checkin_time: "2030-05-05 08:22:02"} // 8 AM.
        ]

        console.log(input);

        // Closest From Now.
        const closestFromNow = times => times.filter(x => Date.now() < new Date(x.checkin_time)).sort((a, b) => new Date(a.checkin_time)*1 - new Date(b.checkin_time)*1)[0]

        // Output.
        const output = closestFromNow(unfinished)
        const output2 = closestFromNow(input)

        // Proof.
        console.log(output) // Undefined
        console.log(output2) // ID 2. 8 AM.


    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

See [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys), [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min), and [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) for more info.

```js
// Input.
const input = [
  {id: 1, checkin_time: "2030-05-05 16:22:02"}, // 4 PM MAY 5 2030. 
  {id: 2, checkin_time: "2030-05-05 08:22:02"}, // 8 AM MAY 5 2030.
  {id: 3, checkin_time: "2000-05-05 13:22:02"}, // 1 PM MAY 5 2030.
  {id: 4, checkin_time: "2000-05-05 11:22:02"}, // 11 AM MAY 5 2030.
]

// Is Before Now
const isBeforeNow = x => (Date.now() > x)

// Generate Key.
const generateKey = x => Math.abs(Date.now()*1 - x*1)

// Closest From Now.
const closestFromNow = (times, restriction) => {

  const m = new Map(times.map(x => {
  
    let date = new Date(x.checkin_time)
     
    if (restriction == 'before') {
      if (isBeforeNow(date)) date = generateKey(date)
      else date = undefined
    }
    
    else if (restriction == 'after') {
      if (!isBeforeNow(date)) date = generateKey(date)
      else date = undefined
    }
    
    else {
      date = generateKey(date)
    }
    
    return [date, x]
    
  }))
  
  m.delete(undefined)
  
  return m.get(Math.min(...m.keys()))
}

// Proof.
console.log('Closest Before Now', closestFromNow(input, 'before')) // ID 3.
console.log('Closest After Now', closestFromNow(input, 'after')) // ID 2.
console.log('Closest From Now In General 1', closestFromNow(input)) // ID 3.
console.log('Closet From Now In Generate 2', closestFromNow([...input, {id: 11, checkin_time: "2020-05-05 11:22:02"}])) // ID 11.
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention my data object with the times. I get an undefined because the `checkin_time` property is a string instead of numbers/Date.now()

Comment: Sure. Wrapping them in `new Date()` should do the trick. See above.

Comment: I got undefined back from it. I'll add my console.logs, maybe I don't see something that's not right

Comment: Alright, I figured out that it only works for times older than now. I would like to have times in the past, and then the closest one.

Comment: I've improved the algorithm. See above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
methods: {
    getLog() {

        var bigestElem = null;
        var closestTime  = 0;
        var elemTime = 0;
        this.users.forEach(element => {

            element.logs.forEach((log) => {
              elemTime =  new Date(log.checkin_time).getTime()
              if(log.finished === false && elemTime > closestTime){
                closestTime = elemTime;
                bigestElem = log;
              }
                this.Logs.push(log);

            })

        });
        console.log(bigestElem);
        return bigestElem
      



    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function as :

```
const input = [
  {id: 1, checkin_time: "2030-05-05 10:22:02"}, // 10 AM. 
  {id: 2, checkin_time: "2030-05-05 08:22:02"} // 8 AM.
]


function findNearestTime(times){
  let currentTime = Date.now();
  let diff = times.map(time => {
    return Math.abs(currentTime - Date.parse(time.checkin_time));
  })

  let i = diff.indexOf(Math.min(...diff));

  return times[i].checkin_time;
}

let latest = findNearestTime(input);
alert("nearest time is :" + latest)
```

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmhu4oLb/17/)

Reference: [`Date.now()`](https://jsfiddle.net/mmhu4oLb/17/) and [`Date.parse()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?q=https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjckMyrhqPaAhXCPY8KHVXNC0kQFggLMAA&usg=AOvVaw1SFBbx156hzGFe-BqulQ8l)

Comment: This will not work directly since the times are properties of an object and not an item from the array. I will update my question with an sample object.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution `returns` `2030-05-05 10:22:02` (the `furthest time`)  `Math.abs()` [is required to return the `nearest time`](https://jsfiddle.net/scnqfuya/).

Comment: @ArmanCharan thanks for pointing out... i overlooked the year. It is 2030 :-( not 12018...